# Gradle unable to get plugin in intellij Idea

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, plugins

I have a `build.gradle` file with the following relevant configuration:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '1.1.6'
}
```

Gradle sync is failing in Intellij Idea with the following error:

```
Gradle sync failed: Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.intellij', version: '1.1.6'] was not found in any of the following sources:
            - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
            - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.intellij:org.jetbrains.intellij.gradle.plugin:1.1.6')
            Searched in the following repositories:
            Gradle Central Plugin Repository (1 m 39 s 732 ms)
```

I've been scouring the internet for hours to find why it's happening to no avail. Can someone please help me out here.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have the Maven central repository defined in your `build.gradle` script file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```